# How is the signal mask set in sys_rt_sigreturn?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, pthreads, signals

I have a following C program, say `signal.c`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static void *func(void *arg) {
    sleep(3);
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t td;

    pthread_create(&td, 0, func, NULL);
    pthread_cancel(td);
    pthread_join(td, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

The program is compiled with musl-gcc, which means it uses musl-libc.

I'm wondering how system calls used by this program actually work, so I inspect the program with `strace`, the main results are:

```
[pid 14736] execve("./signal", ["./signal"], 0x55b68a817448 /* 72 vars */) = 0
[pid 14736] arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x603118) = 0
[pid 14736] set_tid_address(0x603330)   = 14736
[pid 14736] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RT_1 RT_2], NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 14736] mmap(NULL, 143360, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa528201000
[pid 14736] mprotect(0x7fa528203000, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
[pid 14736] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1 RT_2], [], 8) = 0
[pid 14736] clone(child_stack=0x7fa528223ed8, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|0x400000, parent_tidptr=0x7fa528223f58, tls=0x7fa528223f20, child_tidptr=0x603330) = 14737
[pid 14736] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], strace: Process 14737 attached
NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 14737] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [],  <unfinished ...>
[pid 14736] rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x40055e, sa_mask=~[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x401820},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 14737] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 14736] <... rt_sigaction resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 14737] nanosleep({tv_sec=3, tv_nsec=0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 14736] tkill(14737, SIGRT_1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 14737] <... nanosleep resumed> {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=999998914}) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
[pid 14736] <... tkill resumed> )       = 0
[pid 14737] --- SIGRT_1 {si_signo=SIGRT_1, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=14736, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 14736] futex(0x7fa528223f60, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 14737] tkill(14737, SIGRT_1)       = 0
[pid 14737] rt_sigreturn({mask=[RT_1]}) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
[pid 14737] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1 RT_2], [RT_1], 8) = 0
[pid 14737] futex(0x7fa528223f60, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
[pid 14736] <... futex resumed> )       = 0
[pid 14737] exit(0 <unfinished ...>
[pid 14736] futex(0x603330, FUTEX_WAIT, 14737, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 14737] <... exit resumed>)         = ?
[pid 14736] <... futex resumed> )       = 0
[pid 14737] +++ exited with 0 +++
[pid 14736] munmap(0x7fa528201000, 143360) = 0
[pid 14736] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 14736] +++ exited with 0 +++
```

What confuses me is the mask set by `sigreturn`, you can see it's `[RT_1]`. According to what I am understanding, `sigreturn` will restore the mask of the thread before it is interrupted by the signal. But we can find that mask set by `sigprocmask` is just an empty set. Focus on the following results:

```
[pid 14737] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [],  <unfinished ...>
[pid 14736] rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x40055e, sa_mask=~[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x401820},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 14737] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 14736] <... rt_sigaction resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 14737] nanosleep({tv_sec=3, tv_nsec=0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 14736] tkill(14737, SIGRT_1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 14737] <... nanosleep resumed> {tv_sec=2, tv_nsec=999998914}) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
[pid 14736] <... tkill resumed> )       = 0
[pid 14737] --- SIGRT_1 {si_signo=SIGRT_1, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=14736, si_uid=1000} ---
[pid 14736] futex(0x7fa528223f60, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 14737] tkill(14737, SIGRT_1)       = 0
[pid 14737] rt_sigreturn({mask=[RT_1]}) = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
[pid 14737] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, ~[RTMIN RT_1 RT_2], [RT_1], 8) = 0
```

In other words, one thing I can't understand is, how come the mask be `[RT_1]` at last (according to the result given by the third parameter of `rt_sigprocmask`, which stands for the old signal mask)? Since it's set as empty at first, and I can't find any other system call changes the mask.

I guess that it maybe the kernel that changes this mask at some time, maybe it will do this under some circumstances, e.g., something like the kernel adds the mask specified by `sigaction` when a thread enters the signal handler, and restores them in `sigreturn`. But related references are too difficult for me to find.

Could anyone give any advice on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing are internal workings of the pthread library. In other words, it's not the kernel that is responsible for adding/removing those signals to/from the signal mask, but the pthread library. Real-time signals are used internally by the pthread library to manage threads. `strace` displays them as `RT_n`. The fact that they are added/removed to/from the mask should not concern you.

Find more information about real-time signals at [`man 7 signal`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) in the "Real-time signals" section.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The pthread libray still executes under user space, so (probably) it can only change the mask via some system call, which specifically I think should be something like `sigprocmask` or `rt_sigprocmask`. But I just can't find such system calls while the mask changes. That's the reason I suspect that it's the kernel that accounts for the change. So I'm wondering what circumstances will cause the kernel to do such change? e.g. kernel will add the signals which is specified by `sigaction` to the mask when entering the signal handler, and restore them in `sigreturn`.

Comment: @function2 as I said, the pthread library does what it needs to. sigreturn must restore the mask of signals set by the user, what happens with the pthread library is just that it also wants to add RT_1 to that mask *for implementation defined reasons*. You don't have to worry about it. What you would have to worry about is if you see sigreturn add for example SIGUSR1 when you didn't have it on the mask.